# ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, minitest

I have a basic static webpage.

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
 end
```

And there is a home.html.erb with just heading. This works perfectly fine in developement but the test

```
 test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title","home | #{@base}"
 end
```

is failing with error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass
```

Its showing error in application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This is the line shown as causing error. What is causing the problem?

Its working when I revome the stylesheet_link_tag.

```
 *= require_tree 
 *= require_self
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

This is my application.css. There are two other scss files in the stylesheet directory.

Found the problem and fixed it. But dont understand why its happening. Bootstrap had to be moved to the sass file in the same directory and there is no error. But why is it happening? Its working in developement.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because the app is looking for a .scss extension. As you said your filename is `application.css` rename it to `application.css.scss` and it will work.