# Global error handler for specific case. Undefined method 'public_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, gcloud

`ruby '2.5.1'`

`rails '5.1.7'`

My project is for sound management. All uploaded files are in the cloud storage - sounds/sound images/album images and etc.

But some files on cloud storage are absent. And for following code in view:

```
.row
  - @sounds.each do |sound|
    .col-md-2
      .play{ "image-src": "#{sound.image.url(:small)}", style: "background: url(#{sound.image.url(:small)});" }
```

I get following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `public_url' for nil:NilClass)
```

There are a lot of such cycles (`@sounds.each`) in the project, so I would not want to rewrite each one.

**How to write an error handler for such case? So that in absence of files in storage, sound is skipped.**

*Maybe there is a way to write code in `application_controller.rb` or something similar?*

I use `gem 'carrierwave-google-storage'` for images and `gem 'google-cloud-storage'` for attachment.

Comment: How do you set `@sounds`?

Comment: @spickermann For this example - `@sounds = Sound.approved.last(10)`

Comment: @romnoks What do you want to do when the `sound` has no `image`? You could skip them entirely in the scope (e.g. `Sound.where.not(image: nil)...`), or only skip them in that loop (`- next unless sound.image`), or use a placeholder image (perhaps define this behaviour in `Sound#image`?), ... Or maybe add a validation rule that all sounds must have an image?

Comment: The fact is that `sound.image` is not `nil`. The error is called only when `sound.image.url` or `sound.image.public_url` method is registered.
Therefore, I cannot put such a simple condition.

Comment: Maybe I need to write my own exception to handle it?

Comment: _"But some files on cloud storage are absent"_ – why are those files missing? And why do you still have references to those missing files?

Comment: @Stefan This can happen for variety of reasons. Files have not yet been uploaded/sidekiq has not finished working/internal error for path and etc.

Comment: @romnoks working with incomplete or corrupted data is always a mess. If your upload mechanics / background workers don't work properly or have concurrency issues, I'd rather work on that part. Maybe you could add an upload state (uploading / processing / done). However, merely "fixing" the output will just conceal the underlying problems, not solve them.

Comment: @Stefan Right now I need a solution for my question. In the future I will fix rest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some cases where the error `` ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `public_url' for nil:NilClass) `` occurs.

Looking on the Community, it seems that there are some options/ways that can fix this error and it would depend on the way that your code and application is configured. For this reason, I would recommend you to take a look at the following posts and answers, to check if they help you. :)

- [ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891355/actionviewtemplateerror-actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method)
- [Railstutorial ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931968/railstutorial-actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-email-for-nilnilc)
- [Ruby on rails : undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass , what causes this? when i add record to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076462/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-map-for-nilnilclass-what-causes-this-when)

Let me know if the information helped you!